# Is "LED Therapy" clinically effective?

Tags: medical-science

An article in today's Guardian contains a number of claims about "LED therapy" (emphasis mine):

> The Healite uses light-emitting diode (LED) technology, delivered at a wavelength of 830nm, to **promote cellular function**. LEDs may be blue, red, or yellow. Blue lights are used to **treat acne**, **killing the bacteria** that are its cause and **regulating excess oil**. Red lights **stimulate collagen and elastin**, the two holy grails of anti-ageing. Yellow lights **help with wound healing and rejuvenation**, and **temporarily increase blood circulation**. ...
>
> He [Dr Glen Calderhead] believes LED therapy could, in the future, be deployed far more widely. “Anything that involves **wound healing** and **pain attenuation**. It will **work on the muscular-skeletal system**. It will **work on nerve injury**. Recently, it has been used in **cerebral trauma, such as stroke**. ...
>
> Dr Dennis Gross: "LED gets to the heart of that matter: you will have **more collagen**, and it stays there – it’s yours. It’s **one of the most efficacious treatments in dermatology**" ...
>
> Hannah Measures: "in trials, some patients have said it **helps with pain relief**" ...
>
> Dr Glen Calderhead: "We have proved that **collagen and elastin are both improved by LLLT**"

[Beauty and the beam: the future of LED therapy looks bright](https://www.theguardian.com/fashion/2019/oct/27/beauty-and-the-beam-the-future-of-led-therapy-looks-bright), Rachel Cooke, The Guardian, Sunday 27 October 2019

Is LED Therapy more effective than placebo in: 
1) Promoting cellular function? 
2) Treating acne? 
3) Killing bacteria? 
4) Regulating excess oil? 
5) Stimulating / improving collagen and elastin? 
6) Helping with wound healing and rejuvenation? 
7) Temporarily increasing blood circulation? 
8) Attenuating pain? / Helping with pain relief? 
9) Working on the muscular-skeletal system? 
10) Working on nerve injury?

11) Is it an effective treatment for cerebral trauma, such as stroke?

12) Is it one of the most efficacious treatments in dermatology?

Comment: Twelve / thirteen questions in one!  Still missing any claim on aphrodisiac effects or killing cancer ;-)  It is notable that this article is in the Fashion and not the Science pages of The Guardian...